# Is a Firestore document locked when read by the server (cloud-function) in a Transaction?

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I know Firestore uses locks for Transactions in the SERVER (cloud-functions), as explained by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOVSr0OsAoU

The video explains in detail how Transactions work in the CLIENT (and it's not using locks there), but doesn't do such a good job for SERVER Transactions.

Which of these is true (about SERVER Transactions)?:

1) A document is locked by `get`s in a server Transaction, so that other server Transactions cannot `get` it before the first Transaction is finished.

2) A document is locked by `get`s in a server Transaction, but only for writes, so that other server Transactions can get it but not modify it before the first transaction is finished.

3) A document is NOT locked by `get`s in a server Transaction, only writes.

**EDIT:** I need authoritative sources (documentation or some reference in video or blogs from someone in the Firebase Team).

Answer (score 8):

Server side transactions work in general like client libraries but instead of that concurrency model tehnique mentioned in that video, work in the traditional way of locking data. So even if you use a transaction on a single document or on a query, those documents will be locked till the transaction is complete.

To answer your question, because a transaction that is coming from a cloud function is taking place internally (can take a few milliseconds), the documents are locked for that amount of time. This means that those documents can not be taken or changed by any other transactions.

> 1) A document is locked by gets in a server Transaction, so that other server Transactions cannot get it before the first Transaction is finished.

Correct.

> 2) A document is locked by gets in a server Transaction, but only for writes, so that other server Transactions can get it but not modify it before the first transaction is finished.

It makes no sense for another transaction to get a locked document. Why to try to get such a document since it cannot be changed? Moreover, a locked document might have by the time the transaction completes, different values. Between the start of the transaction and when it completes, some properties within the document are changed.

> 3) A document is NOT locked by gets in a server Transaction, only writes.

The document is locked once the cloud function run the transaction and the lock is released when the transaction is completed.

**Edit:**

> It does make sense for another transaction to get a locked document. It cannot be changed, but if it can be read

I was referring strictly in terms of writing. All documents can be read, no matter if the document is locked or not.

> if you just want to read the value

If you just want to read the value, there is nothing to worry about. There are no locks on documents when it comes to reads.

> Maybe you need to read some value to make a decision regarding changing another document, or even just showing some info to the user.

It will work perfectly fine.

> Also, depending on the transaction, you don't care if the document changes within the next second. For example, if the user wants to know the money amount in his bank account, you can show a value from one second before, no problem.

Yes, that's correct. There are no restrictions when it comes to read operations and regarding your example, yes, it's fine. This is also working in one of my projects.

> Could you please point me to their sources?

There are many resources out there that explain how traditional way of locking data work. The server side transactions are working this way, as Todd Kerpelman confirmed in the liked video. The purpose of this locking is to serve and protect shared resources (documents).

> I really need to be absolutely sure of that, so I need the sources, or else someone from the Firebase team confirming them.

Let's also hope that someone from the Firebase team will take the time and look at this but I'm not sure I understand what are your concerns? Do you think that while a transaction is taking place, you won't be ablte to read the documents? Or?

Comment: Alex, it does make sense for another transaction to get a locked document. It cannot be changed, but if it can be read that's OK if you just want to read the value. Maybe you need to read some value to make a decision regarding changing another document, or even just showing some info to the user. Also, depending on the transaction, you don't care if the document changes within the next second. For example, if the user wants to know the money amount in his bank account, you can show a value from one second before, no problem.

Comment: Regarding your answers, thank you for taking your time to write them. Could you please point me to their sources? I really need to be absolutely sure of that, so I need the sources, or else someone from the Firebase team confirming them.

Comment: Please see my answers regarding your comments.

Comment: To answer your question: We developed a Firebase simulator, which we use for tests and works well. However, we need to simulate the server transactions too, so we need to know exactly how they work.

Comment: I understand, so if you need mode infos, just let me know. Btw, nice idea and good luck with that :)

Answer (score -1):

According to the Firestore documentation regarding [Transactions and Batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions),

A transaction consists of any number of `get()` operations followed by any number of write operations such as `set()`, `update()`, or `delete()`. In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

**Conclusion**: A document is not locked by `get()`s in a server transaction. But when a document is modified by another transaction after it is `get()` in the current transaction, will cause the current transaction to retry so that the updated document is `get()` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, that documentation section starts with "Using the Cloud Firestore client libraries...". So this refers to the CLIENT, not to the server. My question is about SERVER Transactions.